# Include Unmanaged DLL from Nuget package to web Deploy package

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I have Nuget package which contains unmanaged DLL and target to copy this DLL to output folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
      <Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="CopyFilesToOutputDirectory">
          <ItemGroup>
              <MyPackageSourceFile Include="$(SolutionDir)\packages\somepackage\unmanaged\*.dll" />
          </ItemGroup>
          <Copy SourceFiles="@(MyPackageSourceFile)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" />
      </Target>
</Project>
```

This perfectly works when I am building project(Using Visual Studio)

However if I want to create publish package(To File System, or Web Deploy again using VS) those dlls are not included.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you refer those DLLs in your project?

Comment: No,  don't include it

Comment: I think you need to create a dummy function to refer. I have seen in SO itself somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Include Unmanaged DLL from Nuget package to web Deploy package

You can add another target after target `AfterBuild` in your NuGet package to dynamically include those unmanaged DLL files to your project file or simple add the target to the project file.

To accomplish this, add a target with target order `AfterTargets="AfterBuild"` in your NuGet package:

```
  <Target Name="AddUnmanagedDll" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">  
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="$(OutputPath)\*.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

But this target will add all dll files, including managed dll files. To resolve this issue, we need to **change previous target AfterBuild to add another copy task to copy those unmanaged dll files to a separate folder**:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="CopyFilesToOutputDirectory">
    <ItemGroup>
      <MyPackageSourceFile Include="$(SolutionDir)packages\somepackage\unmanaged\*.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(MyPackageSourceFile)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(MyPackageSourceFile)" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)UnmanagedDll" />
  </Target>
```

After add the another copy task `<Copy SourceFiles="@(MyPackageSourceFile)" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)UnmanagedDll" />` to copy the unmanaged dll files to the separate folder `$(ProjectDir)UnmanagedDll`.

Then we could change the ItemGroup `<Content Include="$(OutputPath)\*.dll" />` in the target `AddUnmanagedDll` to `<Content Include="UnmanagedDll\*.dll" />`

So the targets in the NuGet package should be:

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="CopyFilesToOutputDirectory">
    <ItemGroup>
      <MyPackageSourceFile Include="$(SolutionDir)packages\app.1.0.0\unmanaged\*.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(MyPackageSourceFile)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(MyPackageSourceFile)" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)UnmanagedDll" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="AddUnmanagedDll" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">  
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="UnmanagedDll\*.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

After publish the project, those unmanaged are included in the web Deploy package:

[image]