# Including Unmanaged DLL in NuGet Package Using csproj

Tags: .net-core, nuget

I'm developing a .NET Core 2.1 library that depends on an unmanaged DLL. I'd like to include the unmanaged DLL in the NuGet package as well. The problem that I am running into is that if I try to specify all of the information in the `.csproj` file, the `dotnet build` process throws the following warning:

```
warning NU5100: The assembly 'content\lib\subdir\somedll.dll' is not 
    inside the 'lib' folder and hence it won't be added as a reference 
    when the package is installed into a project. Move it into the 
    'lib' folder if it needs to be referenced.
```

[I know that I can embed the unmanaged DLLs by writing a `.nuspec`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400472/include-unmanaged-dll-from-nuget-package-to-web-deploy-package) (in fact, I have). However, it seems like I shouldn't need to write one with the latest `.csproj` file format.

**Question:** How can I use the `.csproj` file to embed unmanaged DLLs in a NuGet package?

- Specifying `<ItemGroup><None>` in the `.csproj` file seems to include the files in the output directory but they do not make it into the NuGet package.
- Specifying `<ItemGroup><Content>` in t he `.csproj` file will get them added to the NuGet package but in the Content directory instead of in the Lib directory.

If I really have to have both a `.csproj` file and a `.nuspec` file, what is the best practice for where to put the metadata? In t he `.csproj` file? In the `.nuspec` file? Maintain and sync both? Is there a something in the tool chain that can do this for me?

I'm working in Visual Studio Code V1.24, and .NET Core/dotnet V2.1.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to specify explicit package path metadata on the element so that the dll/so/dylib file ends up at the right place in the package so that it is recognised as runtime-specific native DLL:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="unmanaged.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="runtimes\win-x64\native" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I was able to get rid of the `.nuspec` file and now I can generate the build and NuGet package only using a single call to `dotnet build`.

Comment: @martin-ullrich I tried this exact snippet and have successfully packaged the dlls I want. https://i.imgur.com/SiF3sZU.png (in the screenshot I put them in the same folder as the managed .dll, that is in fact automatically extracted and used) However, neither installing the NuGet package nor upon compiling the program, that uses the NuGet package, extracts those files. `runtimes\win-x64\native` remains empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: nvm, Figured it out^^
Adding the details involved with an extra answer

Answer (score 0):

To add some details to the answer provided by @martin-ullrich, the example provided was incomplete for my use-case. I needed unmanaged .dlls to be extracted automatically when that NuGet package is installed. This required the added `PackageCopyToOutput="true"` to be set. There are some more nasty details  regarding this type of inclusion, which I have captured here: https://github.com/Ruslan-B/FFmpeg.AutoGen/pull/240

### Packaging ffmpeg *.dlls in a nuget package for automatic extraction

You may package the ffmpeg .dlls required to run your code in a NuGet package. When a user installs your NuGet package, the ffmpeg .dlls will be automatically extracted into the directory of the binary / assembly, without the user having to paste them manually. This opens up the door for a small footprint, project specific ffmpeg library, e.g. without uneccesary baggege like 10s of MBs of Networking code. Because the ffmpeg .dlls are not managed C# code, the packaging requires manual editing of Visual Studio's `.csproj` file, after enabling your library to be build as a NuGet package. AFAIK `nuget pack` on other OSs also honors these settings.

#### .csproj settings

Since Visual Studio 2017, the generation of a `.nuspec` file is *not* required anymore. Put the .dlls in a subfolder (here `ffmpeg\`) in your project. In the `<ItemGroup>` tag create a `<None>` or `<Content>` tag. Specify the files to be included via the `Include` property. (Everything is case-sensitive, so `include` is invalid.) Set `Pack` to `true` and `PackagePath` to the target path in the nuget package. `lib\$(TargetFramework)` would place it at the same place as the binary (unless `TargetFramework` is undefined). You may verify that everything is correctly packaged in the resulting `*.nupkg` file with [NuGetPackageExplorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer). Most crucially, specify `PackageCopyToOutput` as `true`, which performs the extraction and copying upon build.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="FFmpeg.AutoGen.Bindings.DynamicallyLoaded" Version="5.1.1.1" />
  <None Include="ffmpeg\*.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="lib\$(TargetFramework)" PackageCopyToOutput="true" />
</ItemGroup>
```

#### Extraction not performed upon enabling PackageCopyToOutput in a NuGet package Update

Visual Studio 2022 has a bug, where extraction/copying is not performed, after enabling this packaging behaviour and pushing it as a NuGet package update, when it wasn't enabled previously. To remedy this, right click your project, that consumes this NuGet package, click `clean` and after that `rebuild`. Now the consuming App should extract the .dlls going forward.