# How to handle indirect dependencies for .NET standard library

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-standard

I am creating a class library "DeviceManager.DLL" that targets .NET standard 2.0, this library depends on another.NET Library "XNet.DLL", I added reference to it, "XNet.Dll" depends on another C++ library "y.DLL", "y.DLL" must exist in the same path as "XNet.DLL" to get the application working. Finally, I will create a WPF application and add reference to the "DeviceManager.DLL" library, How to make the "y.DLL" be presented in the output folder of the WPF application? how to handle this external dependency?
Note: I am also planning to publish the "DeviceManager.DLL" to the Nuget Packages.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Including Unmanaged DLL in NuGet Package Using csproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51217832/including-unmanaged-dll-in-nuget-package-using-csproj)