# Copy unmanaged DLL from NuGet package to ASP.NET API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dll, nuget-package, csproj

My problem is that I have an unmanaged library in a nuget package that I want to copy in the publish folder of the API that embed it.

Here is a StackoverFlow post that I thought it could work as the final goal seems to be the same as me :
[Include Unmanaged DLL from Nuget package to web Deploy package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400472/include-unmanaged-dll-from-nuget-package-to-web-deploy-package)
And here is how I tried to adapt it to my project :

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" DependsOnTargets="CopyFilesToOutputDirectory">
    <ItemGroup>
      <MyPackageSourceFile Include="$(SolutionDir)Assemblies\libwkhtmltox\64 bits\libwkhtmltox.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(MyPackageSourceFile)" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)" />
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(MyPackageSourceFile)" DestinationFolder="$(ProjectDir)UnmanagedDll" />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="AddUnmanagedDll" AfterTargets="AfterBuild">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="UnmanagedDll\*.dll" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

But it doesn't do anything .

In a more common way I also tried something kind of this :

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="Assemblies\libwkhtmltox\32 bits\libwkhtmltox.dll" />
    <None Remove="Assemblies\libwkhtmltox\64 bits\libwkhtmltox.dll" />
  </ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <ContentWithTargetPath Include="Assemblies\libwkhtmltox\32 bits\libwkhtmltox.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <TargetPath>Assemblies\libwkhtmltox\32 bits\libwkhtmltox.dll</TargetPath>
    </ContentWithTargetPath>

    <ContentWithTargetPath Include="Assemblies\libwkhtmltox\64 bits\libwkhtmltox.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <TargetPath>Assemblies\libwkhtmltox\64 bits\libwkhtmltox.dll</TargetPath>
    </ContentWithTargetPath>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Maybe it could be important to specify that all the projects are in **C# .NET CORE 2.1**

Please tell me if you want any further information.

Comment: When you say it doesnt do anything, is `AfterBuild` definitely getting ran?

Comment: I'm not sure, how can I know ?

Comment: Add `<Message Text="### AfterBuild Running ###" Importance="high" />` below the `<Target ...` line. This should then show in your build output

Comment: So the second <Target> run but not the first

Comment: I would add it to both, with a slightly different message to ensure both blocks are being ran

Comment: That's what i've done and I have the message from the second target but not from the first