# System.DllNotFoundException when calling c++ dll from c# application

Tags: c#, nuget, dllimport

I have a small c++ project that I compile as a 32 bit (x86) dll

I also created a c# class library project and I want to call the c++ dll from it
and eventually, publish this as a nuget so a third party will use it (also compiling it as X86)

in my C# I have the following code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestApp
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        //public const string myDllPath= @"..\..\cppdll.dll";
        public const string myDllPath= @"C:\code\cppApp\Debug\cppdll.dll";
        //public const string myDllPath= @"..\Debug\cppdll.dll";


        [DllImport(myDllPath, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        [DllImport("cppdll.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int AddNumbers(int a, int b);

        public void TestCpp(string[] args)
        {
            res = AddNumbers(5,5);
            Console.WriteLine(res);
        }
    }
}
```

Now I created another C# app that is installing the nuget and testing to see if the code is running as expected.

When I give an absolute path to the dll everything is working fine

but no matter what relative path I try I always get the DllNotFoundException

**I saw posts telling to only write the name of the dll in the DllImport attribute**

**I tried different relative paths**

**I tried copying the DLL to the same folder the NuGet is created**

nothing seems to work

Really need some help here

Comment: Put the dll in the same directory as the executable and make sure all dependencies are available. Don't hard code the full path.

Comment: It is probably "..\..\Debug\cppdll.dll", C++ projects build to the solution directory.  But of course that won't work after you deploy the app, you need to copy the DLL into the C# directory.  And then it is simply "cppdll.dll". 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47400472/include-unmanaged-dll-from-nuget-package-to-web-deploy-package

Comment: @HansPassant unfortunately tried that and it didn't work

Comment: @DavidHeffernan since this is a class library there isn't an executable so not sure where I should put the c++ dll

Comment: There is an executable. But if you have no control over it then things are more tricky. One thing you can do is pinvoke LoadLibrary and call it to load the dll using the full path. Then your existing pinvoke with just name resolve fine.

Comment: Here's a nuget docs issue with links to many other similar questions. You can try reading these and see what solutions other people have posted to try to figure it out: https://github.com/NuGet/learn.microsoft.com-nuget/issues/2070